# How to use mongo db aggregate function in meteor with angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want know how to use mongo db aggregate function in meteor with angular.

I added the below packages:

```
meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate
meteor add monbro:mongodb-mapreduce-aggregation
```

In angular service, I wrote the code like this,

```
function getProductDetailsForCompare (skus) {

          return $meteor.collection( function() {
               return Products.aggregate([{ $match: {$or: [{"sku":"777160-001"},{"sku":"777161-001"},{"sku":"728350-B21"}]}}, {$group : {_id : "$sku", price : {$min : "$price"}}}]);
          });               
     };
```

When i run this code , giving the below exception.

```
TypeError: Products.aggregate is not a function
```

Do i need to do any additional setup?
Do i need to add plugin in app.js?

Comment: It only works on the "server" side. There is no support for aggregation on the client as it just would not make any sense.

Comment: Is there any way that i can do this?

Comment: On the "server", then yes.

Comment: try https://github.com/JcBernack/meteor-reactive-aggregate, it's working really well for me and has had a commit within the past week.

Answer (score 0):

It works only server side. write server side method to calculate aggregate in meteor.

Comment: Not really an "answer" is it, especially since it only echoes the comment that was made 5 minutes before you offerred this. When you have enough reputation then you can comment as well. Not that is was required.

Comment: if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
getRecord: function(){
//Write you code here
}

})

call this function in client side by using Meteor.call("getRecord");

if your function having parameter then pass by argument, while calling function mention it as

 Meteor.call("getRecord",argument1,argument2)